# Serving ASP.NET BoilerPlate API and VUEJS app, CORS blocking clients on network

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

Using ASP.NET Boilerplate template for VUEJS.
Run api and serve VUEJS app.
Can browse from localhost - VUE app is served at localhost:8080
On localhost I can browse to localhost:8080 or my ipaddress 10.1.1.36:8080
both of which work.

When I try browse from any other PC on my network CORS blocks the request.

services.AddCors(
                options => options.AddPolicy(
                    _defaultCorsPolicyName,
                    builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod()
                )
            );

```
        // MVC
        services.AddMvc(
            options => options.Filters.Add(new CorsAuthorizationFilterFactory(_defaultCorsPolicyName))
        ).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
```

As per lots of suggestions on the web I've tried .AllowAny....

There seem to be other unanswered questions with this same issue, so hoping to find a response here.

The simplest solution would appear to be to use .AllowAny... methods, as there shouldn't be any issues with where the request comes from. So I'm confused as to why CORS still gets in the way.

Comment: I have the same problem trying to access from other PCs, but in production works smoothly :/

Comment: Good to know @c